# Как определить корневой веб каталог php при настройках Flash Builder?

Tags: php, apache-flex

Здравствуйте. Делаю Flex проект на Flash Builder с php типом сервера. У меня OpenServer непосредственно на диске C. Пишу корневой веб-каталог C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\ и URL-адрес http://localhost/, выдает ошибку. Пробовала различные варианты, после localhost писала название папки - все то же. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать или хотя бы где узнать эти самые корневой каталог и адрес. А может, с Flash Builderом че-то не то?

Comment: А что происходит при переходе http://localhost/ ? Есть какая небудь ошибка или сообщение ?

Answer (score 0):

Нет, при переходе на локалхост открывается Openserver. Наверное, нужно корневой каталог Openservera, а я не знаю, где это.